# I'd like to add radio buttons to the Rails search function to allow narrowing the search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## What I want to come true

I want to implement a search function using radio buttons. I want to be able to narrow down the search using radio buttons and search words.

I've gotten as far as how to implement search, but I can't figure out how to narrow it down with radio buttons. I would like to know how to do this.

## code

**View**

```rb
    <div class="form">
        <%= form_with url: search_path, method: 'get' do |form| %>
            <div class="search">
                <%= form.text_field :search %>
                <%= form.submit "Search" %>
            </div>
#I don't know how to send the value of a radio button.
            <div class="radio">
                <%= form.label :search_check_box,"all", {value: :all} %>
                <%= form.radio_button :search_check_box, :all %>

                <%= form.label :search_check_box,"public", {value: : public} %>
                <%= form.radio_button :search_check_box, :public %>
                <%= form.label :search_check_box,"not_ public", {value: :not_ public} %>
                <%= form.radio_button :search_check_box, :not_publick %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

**controller**

```rb
  def search
    @movies = Movie.search(params[:search])
  end
```

**model**

```rb
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    def self.search(search)
        if search
            Movie.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
        else
            Movie.all
            end
    end
end
```

Comment: You will need to generate a where query based on the params

Comment: I think you pass in an ActionController::Parameters instance perhaps you need search_params[:search]? I assume that would be the contents of your form.text_field :search form field but You did not supply the code from search_params.

Comment: @Smek Sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You're falling to the classic trap of using a single class (Movie) to do way too much. Create a separate model to use to wrap the logic for searching:

```rb
class MovieQuery
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  VISIBILITY_OPTIONS = ["all", "public", "private"]

  attribute :name
  attritute :visiblity

  def to_scope(base: Movie.all)
    base.tap do |b|
      b = base.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{ name }%") if name.present? 
      b = base.where(visiblity: visiblity) if ["public", "private"].include?(visiblity)
    end
  end
end
```

This model is not saved to the database - it simply serves to bind the user input to an object and apply the search filters. Its also the local place to add stuff like validations.

Then bind the form to your model:

```
<%= form_with model: @movie_query || MovieQuery.new,  url: search_path, method: 'get' do |form| %>
  <div class="search">
    <%= form.label :name, 'Search by name' %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <%= form.label :visiblity %>   
    <%= form.collection_radio_buttons :visiblity, 
                                      MovieQuery::VISIBILITY_OPTIONS,  
                                      :itself,
                                      :humanize
     %>     
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Search' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`collection_radio_buttons` is really meant to be used with objects (models) and the third and forth arguments are the text and label methods called on each object in the collection. By using `itself` and `humanize` you can use it with a simple array.

Then setup your controller to bind the inputs back to the model:

```rb
class MoviesController
  def search
    @movie_query = MovieQuery.new(search_parameters)
    @movies = @movie_query.to_scope
  end

  private

  def search_parameters
    params.fetch(:movie_query) # its an optional parameter
          .permit(:name, :visibility)
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you have to figure out in your model how you actually want deal with input from the radio button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
What is going on? It looks very complicated to me. All I want is for the characters I type to be retrieved from the DB and displayed. And I just want to use the radio buttons to narrow down the search. I have the radio buttons stored as a boolean in a column of the Movie model, ``is_showing``. 1 is showing, 0 is not showing. I want to adjust the radio buttons for public, unpublished, and all.

Comment: Its not really going to be less complicated if you skip using a model.